# Access PCF VCAP_Services from Spring boot Angular App

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy an Angular Application as a Jar ( Maven) in Pivotal Cloud foundary. I am trying to access the VCAP_SERVICES varialble in the PCF inside the application.

`I was using the process.env.VCAP_SERVICES from the proxy.conf.js.`

Since this is deployed and run as a Jar in the PCF, I think the node server is not started and the VCAP_SERVICES variable is not accessible. It was showing as "undefined".  I am looking for any pointers to access the VCAP_SERVICES from angular code. Can someone please help or give link to any blog/tutorials for this. Thank you.

Comment: Angular runs on the client browser, `VCAP_SERVICES` is on the server side. You need something to bridge the two. I don't know anything about your app, but you mentioned Spring Boot so you probably need to have an endpoint that passes the information from the server to the client. I think that's what you're trying to do with proxy.conf.js, but if you're deploying to PCF as a Java app, you're not going to have node.js installed (at least not without some additional work).

Comment: @DanielMikusa Yes we dont have the node.js installed. Is there any other way to access the VCAP_SERVICES in a spring boot angular APP. Like having an application.yml or something. We dont have any API endpoints in this application.

Comment: If you install Spring Boot Actuator it will expose a endpoint with all environment variables.See the `env` endpoint: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints. Do be careful though as you need to secure this endpoint as well, since your env variables will probably contain sensitive info.